# How to get models order by relation value null and not null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 I have a question. There is `Post` model and `Comment` model. I want to get all posts with comments, whether they have comments or not. And I want to order posts by their comments, such as posts have comments are front, posts don't have comments are behind. How do I finish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) and order them by comments count as:

```
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')
        ->orderBy('comments_count', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

This will order the posts which have `comments` at first place and rest will follow it.

> To count the number of results from a relationship without actually
>   loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a
>   `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forget this method. Thanks.